# Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'kappa' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, node.js

I keep getting the following error code

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'kappa' in 'where clause'
```

when executing this script in nodejs

```
connection.query('SELECT balance FROM members WHERE username = kappa', function(err, data) {
        if (!err)
         console.log(data);
        else
         console.log(err);

    });
```

im unsure why this is happening, is my syntax wrong or something?

Comment: Missing quote on kappa.

Answer (score 7):

For comparing with strings use single quotes like:

```
"SELECT balance FROM members WHERE username = 'kappa'"
```

try with this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the same codes in MySQL Workbench, it will tell the same error.

```
SELECT balance FROM members WHERE username = kappa
// Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'kappa' in 'where clause'

SELECT balance FROM members WHERE username = "kappa"
// No error for this codes.
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT balance FROM members WHERE username = "'+kappa+'"
```

Comment: You are assuming that kappa is a JavaScript variable.... Why? Yet the OP has already indicated via comments that putting `'kappa'` instead of `kappa` fixed their issue.